# Why's 馬 (horses) the semantic component of 騙 (to fool, to defraud)?

Tags: etymology, glyph-origin

1. I don't understand how horses (馬) appertain to deceiving and swindling (騙). I'm uneducated on horses. Is there evidence that horses swindle humans or other horses?
2. And I don't understand how the meanings underlined in red below (leap into a saddle, mount a horse) to deceiving and swindling either.

[image]

Above is [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E9%A8%99#). Below is *Oxford Chinese Dictionary* (2010) p 553.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0. A word on **rebus (假借)**: assume I were to create an emoji writing system for English. I don't exactly have an emoji for the verb 'to leave'; but what if I use a pre-existing emoji  'leaf' to represent the meaning 'to leave' instead, based on their similarity in pronunciation? Now we can't possibly link the *meaning* of 'leaf' to 'to leave' (much like how you tried to link 'horse' to 'to deceive'); they are only linked *phonetically*. That is the concept of rebus.

Put simply,

1. `騙` meaning 'to leap into the saddle; to mount a horse' is a phono-semantic compound (形聲). The phonetic component is `扁` and the semantic component (an action truly related to horse) is `馬`. We rarely use this meaning anymore in modern Chinese.
2. `騙` meaning 'to deceive' is however **rebus (假借)**. The form `騙` is used to represent a perhaps originally formless character meaning 'to deceive' based on their similarity in sound. The original meaning of `騙` however is gradually *replaced* overtime (which nullifies the semantic relevance of `馬`).

   Some scholars (e.g. 王力) are of the belief that the character for 'to deceive' should have been `諞` instead, which makes the semantic component (`言`) more relevant to its meaning. But Baxter-Sagart (2014) treats `諞` and `騙` as distinct characters when reconstructing their Old Chinese pronunciations:

   > 騙 piàn < *phjienH* < *phen(ʔ)-s ‘to fool, to cheat’; VN phỉnh
   > [fiŋ C1] ‘coax’ (p.104)
   > 諞 biàn < *bjienX* < *[m-ph]e[r]ʔ ‘insincere words’ （p. 278)
   > 諞 pián < *bjien* < *[m-ph]e[r] ‘insincere words’ (p. 278)

   so the interchangeability between `諞` and `騙` is not well agreed upon.
3. Also consider `球` 'ball': why does it have the semantic component `玉` ('jade') at all? It's rebus again, and it has been noted that `球` and `毬` (`毛` 'feather' being the semantic component) were probably interchangeable.

**References**

Baxter, William H., and Sagart, Laurent. Old Chinese: A New Reconstruction. Oxford University Press, 2014.

Answer (score 0):

馬(horse) is related to 戲(play/ perform)

戲 is related to 假; 扮 (fake; pretend)

假; 扮 is related to 騙 (trick)

In ancient times, children would hold a stick between their legs to pretend to ride a horse, the idiom 青梅竹馬 illustrated it graphically, it is similar to what the performers did in Chinese opera. The opera couldn't use real horses on stage, so they used a horizontally held stick to represent a horse's back and using another stick as a horsewhip to express 'horse riding' and that's where the idiom 扮鬼扮馬 came from